# Win32: HtmlHelp doesn't work from a network share. What's the alternative?

Tags: security, winapi, html-help

Since 2005, when Microsoft prevented HtmlHelp functioning off a network share, e.g.:

```
\\appserver\tos\PointScanner.exe
\\appserver\tos\PointScanner.chm
```

What are we supposed to do instead?

(Given that the application is not installed locally.)

---

To rephrase: What is Microsoft's intended, supported, out-of-the-box, help solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow access via the Registry setting described here:

> [**http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896054/**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896054/)

If you don't want to open any security vulnerabilities by modifying Registry settings your application could also create a local copy of the .chm file, e.g. in the users temp folder (%TMP%) and open the help from there. You can remove the file again when your application exits (in case you don't want to leave anything behind on the user's workstation)

Comment: The registry key is in HKLM, which an application cannot change. Plus, i'd rather not have my application intentionally changing the behaviour of stuff besides chm files - opening up the user to security threats.

Comment: Then why not copy the help file to a local folder (e.g. %TMP%) and open it from there? You can remove the file again when your application exits (in case you don't want to leave anything behind on the user's workstation).

Comment: That's a good suggestion, divo - i hadn't thought of that. You should put that in your answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for copying the comment to the answer. Accepted. It really seems like the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I started with the registry change mentioned by divo.  Eventually I moved from network folder based chm files to actual "html help".   This was easy for me since I use RoboHelp which can generate either format from the same source code.